# Get grouping record from two queries with same id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How to get record with same id that came from two queries?

The first query is :

```
    SELECT
                final.id,
                mutasi.nomor_voucher,
                SUM(detail.pembayaran) as pembayaran

    FROM petty_cash_mutasi_kas mutasi

    INNER JOIN petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran keluar
    ON keluar.id = mutasi.petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran_id

    INNER JOIN job_order_final final
    ON final.id = keluar.job_order_final_id

    INNER JOIN job_order_final_detail detail
    ON detail.job_order_final_id = final.id

    INNER JOIN job_order job_order
    ON job_order.id = final.job_order_id

    WHERE keluar.id IS NOT NULL

    GROUP BY mutasi.id
```

The result is like this:

```
+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | nomor_voucher | pembayaran |
+-----+---------------+------------+
| 215 | CP00000001    | 7500000.00 |
+-----+---------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

And the second query is:

```
    SELECT
        final.id,
        mutasi.nomor_voucher,
        keluar.kasbon_id
    FROM petty_cash_mutasi_kas mutasi

    LEFT JOIN petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran keluar
    ON keluar.id = mutasi.petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran_id

    LEFT JOIN kasbon kasbon
    ON kasbon.id = keluar.kasbon_id

    LEFT JOIN job_order_detail detail
    ON detail.kasbon_id = kasbon.id

    LEFT JOIN job_order job_order
    ON job_order.id = detail.job_order_id

    LEFT JOIN job_order_final final
    ON job_order.id = final.job_order_id

    WHERE
    keluar.id IS NOT NULL
    AND keluar.job_order_final_id IS NULL
```

The result of second query is:

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | nomor_voucher | pembayaran|
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 215 | KB00000001    |       110 |
| 215 | KB00000002    |       111 |
| 223 | KB00000003    |       112 |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

As you can see, there are id with unitque value, `213, 215`
I need the result like this.

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | nomor_voucher | pembayaran|
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 215 | KB00000001    |       110 |
| 215 | KB00000002    |       111 |
| 215 | CP00000001    | 7500000.00|
+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

And also, how to get only id `223`

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | nomor_voucher | pembayaran|
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 223 | KB00000003    |       112 |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

Please give me an advice, what keys that I have to do to get the result like that ?

Comment: The keluar.id IS NOT NULL condition makes the keluar LEFT JOIN to return an INNER JOIN result. Do you want a LEFT JOIN or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from
(yourFirstQuery) q1
left join
(yourSecondQuery
) q2 on q1.id=q2.id
```

This will return first result which you want.

```
SELECT
        final.id,
        mutasi.nomor_voucher,
        keluar.kasbon_id
    FROM petty_cash_mutasi_kas mutasi

    LEFT JOIN petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran keluar
    ON keluar.id = mutasi.petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran_id

    LEFT JOIN kasbon kasbon
    ON kasbon.id = keluar.kasbon_id

    LEFT JOIN job_order_detail detail
    ON detail.kasbon_id = kasbon.id

    LEFT JOIN job_order job_order
    ON job_order.id = detail.job_order_id

    LEFT JOIN job_order_final final
    ON job_order.id = final.job_order_id

    WHERE
    keluar.id IS NOT NULL
    AND keluar.job_order_final_id IS NULL
    and final.id not in
    (
    SELECT
            final.id
FROM petty_cash_mutasi_kas mutasi

INNER JOIN petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran keluar
ON keluar.id = mutasi.petty_cash_bukti_pengeluaran_id

INNER JOIN job_order_final final
ON final.id = keluar.job_order_final_id

INNER JOIN job_order_final_detail detail
ON detail.job_order_final_id = final.id

INNER JOIN job_order job_order
ON job_order.id = final.job_order_id

WHERE keluar.id IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY mutasi.id)
```

This will return second result with id=223

Comment: if my answer solve your problem, please accept is as answer